# Attatch documentation for GLUT in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When programming in Java you can use ctrl+space when starting to write a function, like "Math.c...", and then you get a tooltip with a list of functions in Math that begins with c, and an explanation from the javadoc what that function does.

I'd like to have the same for the functions defined in gl.h and glut.h now however. The autocomplete still works, but there is no entry from the documentation of those library functions, nor the functions from stdlib.

How do i make them appear?

(In Java you could go to preferences/installed JREs/java-7 click edit, and then click javadoc location, but i cant find out how you do that in C++).